# Django for loop looping only once through queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project and I ran into one problem. I'm looping through a queryset and the for loop is running only once without giving any error. This problem was not happening earlier but now it came out of nowhere. below is my code.

views.py

```
ward = Student.objects.get(id = request.POST.get('ward'))
request.session['student'] = request.POST.get('ward')
fees = Fee.objects.get(classes = ward.classes)
extras = ExtraFee.objects.filter(student = ward)
ex = ExtraFee.objects.filter(student = ward).values('title').annotate(Count('title'))
print(ex)
for e in ex:
    print(e)
    title = e['title']
    if e['title__count'] > 1:
       print(title)
       extra = ExtraFee.objects.filter(title = e['title'], student = ward)
       amount = 0
       fine = 0
       for ex in extra:
         amount = int(ex.amount) + amount
         total = amount
       for exs in extras:
         fine = int(exs.amount) + fine
         totalfine = fine
         return render(request, "dashboard/parent_fees.html", {"students": students, "parent": parent, "ward": ward, "fees": fees, "extras": extras, "totalfine": totalfine, "total": total, "title": title})
    else:
      fine = 0
      for e in extras:
         fine = int(e.amount) + fine
         totalfine = fine
         return render(request, "dashboard/parent_fees.html", {"students": students, "parent": parent, "ward": ward, "fees": fees, "extras": extras, "totalfine": totalfine})
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Please provide the error you're getting, and on which line

Comment: The 'return' statements. Comment them out for once and see how many times the loop works.

Using a return inside of a loop, will break it and exit the method/function even if the iteration still not finished.

Comment: @Zionsof As i said in my description I'm not getting any error. The loop is running once and that's it. everything is normal

Comment: @ArindamRoychowdhury It worked. But what's the explaination?

Comment: @DaljitSingh Using a return inside of a loop, will break it and exit the method/function even if the iteration still not finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a return inside of a loop, will break it and exit the method/function even if the iteration still not finished.

So never use 'return' inside a loop unless you know what you are doing.